# Control variable already in use - simple VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

Getting control variable in use for this, I guess because of "ws", can someone help how to fix? Thanks

```
Sub CreateNewWBS()
    Dim wbThis As Workbook
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strFilename As String
    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wbThis.Worksheets
        strFilename = wbThis.Path & "/" & ws.Name
        ws.Copy
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        For Each ws In wbNew.Worksheets
            ws.Cells.Copy
            ws.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wbNew.SaveAs strFilename
        wbNew.Close
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim ws2 as Worksheet` and use that instead? Also you're missing a `Next`.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of `wbThis`?  Surely, it is just `ThisWorkbook`, which will not (and literally *can not*) change during the macro execution?

Comment: @Chronocidal I guess just to differentiate between wbNew. The code is working without the Copy Paste Values portion.

Comment: @BigBen Can I get guidance how to "Set" wb2 before the Copy Paste Value portion?

Comment: I proposed `ws2` and you don't `Set` anything. `For Each ws2 in wbNew.Worksheets`, `ws2.Cells.Copy`, `ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

Comment: @BigBen Ok that's what I had initially but keep getting errors. Turns out it was an issue with my Next statements. Fixed that and code works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: ...  Your second loop is unnecessary: as it currently stands `wbNew` will only ever contain 1 worksheet.  You only need a single `For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` loop

Answer (score 2):

Used ws2 and fixed Next statements, works now:

```
Sub CreateNewWBS()
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim strFilename As String
Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
For Each ws In wbThis.Worksheets
    strFilename = wbThis.Path & "/" & ws.Name
    ws.Copy
    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        For Each ws2 In wbNew.Worksheets
            ws2.Cells.Copy
            ws2.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Next
    wbNew.SaveAs strFilename
    wbNew.Close
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
Sub CreateNewWBs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Copy
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value = .Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value
            .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & ws.Name
            .Close
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I have removed the second `For` loop, which was causing you issues (both because you had `For` without `Next`, and because you were trying to reuse an existing variable) on the basis that `wbNew` only ever contained 1 worksheet, replaced `wbThis` with `ThisWorksheet`, and swapped the `.Copy:.PasteSpecial` with `.Value=.Value` to avoid needing the clipboard.